# Tesseract 4.00.00alpha compilation

Tags: tesseract, leptonica

I installed tesseract 4.00.00alpha and leptonica in ubuntu 16.04 x86. When i am using the following command,

```
tesseract -v
```

The output is

```
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
 leptonica-1.74
  libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8

 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

Which is desired.

But while i am trying to compile my following code,

```c++
#include<baseapi.h>
#include<allheaders.h>
int main(){
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *first=new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
printf("Tesseract version %s\n",first->Version());
printf("leptonica version %s\n",getLeptonicaVersion());
return 0;
}
```

with the command,

```
g++ sample.cpp -o sample.out -I/usr/local/include/leptonica -I/usr/local/include/tesseract -llept -ltesseract
```

The output is,

```
Tesseract version 3.04.01
leptonica version leptonica-1.74
```

Why the previous tesseract version is being shown? Is there any problem with the library files of tesseract and leptonica? Thank you!

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: Can you share how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Please check the answer section. @thewaywewere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was while installing leptonica 1.74, i used a command,

```
sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev
```

and while building tesseract 4.00.00 from source, i used a command,

```
sudo apt-get install libtesseract-dev
```

These above two commands are creating the problem. Actually we dont need install libleptionica-dev and libtesseract-dev since you are building tesseract from source.

I uninstalled both packages and reran my code.

```
sudo apt-get remove libleptonica-dev libletesseract-dev
```

It then worked successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing